# Why aren't the fonts becoming bigger and bigger? Is font-inherit crewing things up?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain to me why the font-size isn't being inherited by the p tag, and by the div and the p tag nested in it? As well as the anchor tag? Shouldn't they be inheriting the body's overwritten font-size:160%, becoming bigger and bigger?

The first part of the css is part of Eric Meyer's reset style as you know. If my understanding is right, shouldn't the font-size property be placed below the font only one for it to take effect? Isn't it simply being overwritten thanks to the cascading effect?

Actually if you try and change that font-size:100%; to something else (eg: 200%) you'll notice it takes no visual effect (no immediate one, at least).

Is it the font: inherit; style that does something I'm not aware of? This is making me quite mad... not figuring this one out.

Thanks in advance people.

DEMO: ' http://tinkerbin.com/GMEyX3is '

```
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      font-size: 100%; 
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline; 
    }

    body{
      font-size: 160%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Paragraph <a href="#">OUTSIDE</a> of div</p>

  <div>
    <p>Paragraph INSIDE of div</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting `font-size: 100%` is ignored here, since the setting `font: inherit` (appearing later) overrides it. Setting `font` always sets all font-related properties, and this includes `font-size: inherit`. The inherited value generally depends on the property, but it is most cases, and in this case, the *computed* value of the parent element. So whatever value the setting of `font-size` for `body` results in, a value in pixels or points, depending on browser, will be used. It is this calculated value, not the percentage, that is inherited.

Browsers that do not support the value `inherit` will just ignore this setting and use `font-size: 100%`, which of course results in the same size.

Comment: So, Jukka K. Korpela, if i understood you correctly, the font-size:100% in Eric Meyer's reset stylesheet is solely to cover up for browsers that do not support the inherit value? But that still leaves the font weight from the headings as bold. Hes ignoring this, I assume, for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Check out Eric’s own explanations at http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/ . (I don’t pretend to understand all of his reasoning, and I’m not a reset stylesheet fan.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had gone through that page already (that and a few others) by him, but found no mention to the reasoning on the use of the font-size property. But ye, anyway, you cleared my doubt. Thank you very much sir. Heh. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've set the font-size on the `body` to be 160%. That means that all the elements across the page will now have a font-size starting from 60% more than the base font ize used by the browser.

When the font-size is set to 100% in the reset styles, it basically means that the font-size for all the elements will be the same as the base font size of the browser. So even header tags like the `<h1>, <h2>`... will take the same font-size. In order for the font size to become bigger with each nested element, you will have to define a font-size on the div and if required, the p. So perhaps you can do something like:

```
div{
    font-size:200%;
}

p{
    font-size:200%;
}
```

If you define the font-size as 100%, it will inherit the font-size of it's parent element.

Comment: Yes, i get that. What was actually confusing me was not knowing the font-inherit value was the computed value and not the actual percentage. Thanks ;)